# Partially transparent, A xor B alpha blending in cocos2d-x?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x, alphablending, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'd like to blend two `Sprite`s in cocos2d-x, without having these blending with the underlying `Layer`. From the [Wikipedia article about alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), we have the following image:

[image]

I'm interested in achieving the effect as displayed in the "A xor B" category, second row (partially transparent A and B).

I've experimented with different blending functions, like

```
Sprite* sprite1 = Sprite::create("image.png");
BlendFunc bf = { GL_ONE, GL_ZERO };
sprite1->setBlendFunc(bf);

Sprite* sprite2 = Sprite::create("image.png");
BlendFunc bf = { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA };
sprite2->setBlendFunc(bf);

// Add sprites to layer here
```

but I can't imagine what would make this approach work. I believe I need to dive into the rendering pipeline in order to get this right. :/ For instance, I've seen an example over at the OpenGL-forums that claims to [do what I want](https://community.khronos.org/t/how-to-prevent-blending-with-background/63391#post1215061). The author uses the following

```
//clear depthbuffer and render only planes being further in the background
glClearDepth( 0.0 );
glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glDepthFunc( GL_GREATER );

//disable blending and render only color of the planes  
glDisable( GL_BLEND );
glColorMask( true, true, true, false );

//--> RENDER CONTENT

//reset depthbuffer
glClearDepth( 1.0 );
glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glDepthFunc( GL_LESS );

//reset to standard blending
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glColorMask( true, true, true, true );

//--> RENDER CONTENT
```

where he/she is rendering the content twice to achieve the desired result. This doesn't seem like a terribly viable path in the cocos2d-x ecosystem. Is there any way to make this happen using the existing cocos2d-x ver. 3.1 rendering pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is as dirty as it gets. But for the moment, I'll workaround the issue by adding another (identical) sprite. Like so:

```
Sprite* sprite0 = Sprite::create("image2.png");     
// This ensures a lower Z-order than sprite1 and sprite2, 
// but same image and position as sprite2.
sprite0->setBlendFunc(cocos2d::BlendFunc::DISABLE);
Sprite1->setPosition(150.0f, 150.0f);

Sprite* sprite1 = Sprite::create("image1.png");
sprite1->setBlendFunc(cocos2d::BlendFunc::DISABLE);
Sprite1->setPosition(100.0f, 100.0f);

Sprite* sprite2 = Sprite::create("image2.png");
BlendFunc bf = { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA };
sprite2->setBlendFunc(bf);
Sprite2->setPosition(150.0f, 150.0f);
```

Not pretty, but get's the job done.